# Typing a function's return type as a union of the provided arguments' types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

How could one implement the following function safely in TypeScript without resorting to unsafe casts or a large number of function overloads with different permutations of the passed inputs?

```
interface Wrapped<T> {
    type: string;
    data: T;
}

interface WrappedA<T> extends Wrapped<T> {
    type: "a";
}

interface WrappedB<T> extends Wrapped<T> {
    type: "b";
}

type FuncProps<A = never, B = never> = { a?: A[]; b?: B[] };
const func = <A = never, B = never>({ a, b }: FuncProps<A, B>) => {
    const ret: Array<([A] extends [never] ? never : WrappedA<A>) | ([B] extends [never] ? never : WrappedB<B>)> = [];
    if (a != null) {
        const push: Array<WrappedA<A>> = a.map(value => ({ type: "a" as const, data: value }));
        ret.push(...push); // Error: Type 'WrappedA<A>' is not assignable to type '[A] extends [never] ? never : WrappedA<A>'.
    }
    if (b != null) {
        const push: Array<WrappedB<B>> = b.map(value => ({ type: "b" as const, data: value }));
        ret.push(...push); // Error: Type 'WrappedB<B>' is not assignable to type '[B] extends [never] ? never : WrappedB<B>'.
    }
    return ret;
};

// Desired behavior
const ret1 = func({ a: [1] }); // type: WrappedA<number>[]
const ret2 = func({ b: ["1"] }); // type: WrappedB<string>[]
const ret3 = func({ a: [1], b: ["1"] }); // type: (WrappedA<number> | WrappedB<string>)[]
```

I tried using `never` to omit certain types from the returned array's type union but failed to do so correctly.

Comment: Why no overloads? What do you mean "there could be more than 2 parameters"? Why would that affect overloads?

Comment: This seems to need significant refactoring if you want to support more than just A and B.  I'd probably write it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WozXMm), but that's so different from your code that I wonder if that could possibly be what you're looking for.  If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: *"...there could be more than 2 parameters..."* There is only one parameter in your code (a single object parameter that you're destructuring). Do you mean it could have more than two properties? How would you handle that in the actual code?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder @Kay I meant to say that the object could contain more than two properties, and I was curious if it could be done without overloading it more than once while accommodating any number of properties.

@jcalz That's a neat solution for an indefinite number of properties but I'd like to explicitly define them in the `FuncProps` interface. I imagine a scenario where this function is responsible for merging multiple arrays representing different data sources into a final output array where each result is wrapped in an object that contains type information.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. I thought the whole point was to allow more properties.  If you want to limit to just `"a" | "b"` you could write it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/wEjnVN) and then later you can expand it to more properties by adding them to the union.  If that's what you're looking for, great, I could write an answer. If it's not, could you please explain in what way it fails? Thanks!

Comment: @jcalz In my specific case `FuncProps` is a bigger object containing other properties as well that I'm not merging, that's why I wanted to keep it defined this way but needed a solution which didn't require enumerating the different permutations of missing properties.

Comment: I’ll need to see a [mre] of what you’re talking about or I guess I’ll have to disengage. Maybe you could make an effort to see how my suggestion could be adapted to your use case?

Comment: Oh I see you posted your own answer.  Let me know if you want me to write up an answer also, otherwise have a good day! (Well, have a good day either way)

Answer (score 0):

Putting the more specific return type in a function overload got the [desired behavior](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgOpTgB0xAJgHgBUA%20ZAbwFgAoZW5MATxwC5kBnMKUAcwG5q6yXHDBxWhflQC%201aqEixEKdFhy4AgkVIQAHpBC42aDNjxbyAuoxbIARHFuSZVOeGjwkx1XgBC53fqGXqYEJBY0VkwQrLYARo7UztTWKABiAK4gCAAKUAD2mGz46sgAvMggEABu0AA0yD5lFdXQpOVkyHAA-KzqANoAurzIsT0Ng8hSkq4KHigA8jVQADZ5cLjhgsVNlUv1jeW7rQAUmPmFrBlZuQVF6vvEAJS9UBgM%20Md96gPIARAGRj6RygPy6zSWyFYKhCmnUT2QAB9kJ8fD8-gDkECWiDkGDgZDgmo-D4nsRJFsSodsfsdtjiKdzmxLpkcozig9nsh1K84O9oWpYaQkfzfPgSWTErIqAg8iAOMgYCzWItoKt1k12Q16R04PVYpNmdc2fctY8yqRKBFaDK5WBkFAIGAXm98CKNMUhYTReKmoNyXRgDBkXBkABCQ7pZbLM2WwSCG3yzDpNgAC2dvNdJgFHranQAdABbLDHKpwZbpFClUjHDopGIOTpGBNgerCUSsUvllBSR6Pf1x%202OvNJ1PHPPjkcpvuWWjOQSB5H68MVSPRzYD5DN5CT9N8rPe4i52KF4udivm5G1qIxeKNzeyjitkRiZBn7u9-txh1gYfJlNjic-2nK1JhnQcwHSKAQHApxpioAB6eDkAAEQgNhgAdDZYggFM4CqYA8igagt2-ABGJpFSyGtOlYPpSJ%20HthkQ%20hry9d0QHSAtsKgYhBmIh87W-AAmCiWWo2JaNsUjbAYvtkGYus2L8DguBAbheIGfjbXAgBmUSqJ1Wj6L1STpNkpikMU443U0DiuNaRElPwFSeCeQYgA):

```
interface Wrapped<T> {
    type: string;
    data: T;
}

interface WrappedA<T> extends Wrapped<T> {
    type: "a";
}

interface WrappedB<T> extends Wrapped<T> {
    type: "b";
}

type FuncProps<A = never, B = never> = { a?: A[]; b?: B[] };

interface Overload {
    <A = never, B = never>(props: FuncProps<A, B>): Array<([A] extends [never] ? never : WrappedA<A>) | ([B] extends [never] ? never : WrappedB<B>)>;
    <A = never, B = never>(props: FuncProps<A, B>): Array<WrappedA<A> | WrappedB<B>>;
}

const func: Overload = <A, B>({ a, b }: FuncProps<A, B>) => {
    const ret: Array<WrappedA<A> | WrappedB<B>> = [];
    if (a != null) {
        const push: Array<WrappedA<A>> = a.map(value => ({ type: "a" as const, data: value }));
        ret.push(...push);
    }
    if (b != null) {
        const push: Array<WrappedB<B>> = b.map(value => ({ type: "b" as const, data: value }));
        ret.push(...push);
    }
    return ret;
};

// Desired behavior
const ret1 = func({ a: [1] }); // type: WrappedA<number>[]
const ret2 = func({ b: ["1"] }); // type: WrappedB<string>[]
const ret3 = func({ a: [1], b: ["1"] }); // type: (WrappedA<number> | WrappedB<string>)[]
```